# Selenium webscrape not scraping all item information on Amazon

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've been building a webscrape that:
1.) Asks what item you'd like to look for on Amazon
2.) Opens a Chrome browser with Selenium and searches for item
3.) Runs through a pre-set amount of pages (I have it at 1 for time efficiency when debugging)
4.) Scrapes all items information on each page and creates a list of "Product" objects.

The issue I'm having is even with the Try & Except I still don't get all the information for each item.  When debugging I've double and triple checked my xpaths with "Xpath Helper" and don't see where I went wrong.

Below is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from reference_functions import Product
import time
from lxml import html
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime
##  SETTING UP QUESTIONS NEEDED FOR SCRAPE
question_product = "What would you like to search for?\n:"
search_term = "invicta mens watch" #str(input(question_product))
search_terms = search_term.split(" ")
question_export = "Do you want to export all item data to excel?\n:"
export_data = "no"#str(input(question_export))

##  SETTING UP WEBDRIVER 
s = Service('/Users/nicholaskenney/PycharmProjects/Amazon_Scrape/chromedriver')
chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=chrome_options)

##  OPENING URL 
url = "https://www.amazon.com/"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

##  SENDING SEARCH TERMS TO SEARCH BOX FOLLED BY ENDER BUTTON 
search_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, "twotabsearchtextbox")
search_box.send_keys(search_term)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(3)

products_list = []
page = 1

while True:
    if page != 0:
        try:
            driver.get(driver.current_url + "&page=" + str(page))
            time.sleep(3)
        except:
            break
    else:
        break

    tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
    time.sleep(3)
    for product_tree in tree.xpath('//div[contains(@data-cel-widget, "search_result_")]'):
        should_add = True
        title = ""
        price = ""
        url = ""
        number_of_reviews = ""
        review_score = ""
        previous_price = ""

        try:
            ##  Finding Title of item  
            try:
                title = product_tree.xpath('.//span[@class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]/text()')
            except Exception as e:
                print("This is from first title try: " + e)
                title = product_tree.xpath('.//span[@class="a-size-base-plus a-color-base a-text-normal"]/text()')

            ## FINDING CURRENT PRICE OF ITEM 
            price = product_tree.xpath('.//span[@class="a-price-whole"]/text()')

            ##  FINDING NUMBER OF REVIEWS OF EACH ITEM
            try:
                number_of_reviews = product_tree.xpath('.//span[@class="a-size-base"]/text()')
            except:
                number_of_reviews = product_tree.xpath('.//span[@class="a-size-base a-color-base s-underline-text"]/text()')

            ## REVIEW SCORE FOR EACH ITEM  
            try:
                review_score = product_tree.xpath('.//span[@class="a-icon-alt"]/text()')
            except:
                review_score = product_tree.xpath('.//span[@class="a-size-base a-color-base s-underline-text"]/text()')

            ##  FINDING LINK FOR EACH ITEM
            try:
                links = product_tree.xpath('.//a[@class="a-link-normal s-link-style a-text-normal"]')
                for link in links:
                    if 'href' in link.attrib:
                        url = (str(link.attrib['href']))
            except:
                links = product_tree.xpath('.//a[@class="a-link-normal s-underline-text s-underline-link-text s-link-style a-text-normal"]')
                for link in links:
                    if 'href' in link.attrib:
                        url = (str(link.attrib['href']))

            ## PREVIOUS PRICE SCRAPE 
            try:
                previous_price = product_tree.xpath('.//span[@class="a-price a-text-price"]//span['
                                                    '@class="a-offscreen"]/text()')
            except:
                previous_price = price
        except:
            print("exception")
            should_add = False

        ## IF ALL INFORMATION IS SCRAPED (SHOULD_ADD IS TRUE) CREATE PRODUCT OBJECTS FOR EACH ITEM AND APPEND TO PRODUCT LIST
        product = Product(price, title, url, number_of_reviews, review_score, previous_price)
        if should_add == True:
            products_list.append(product)

    page = page - 1

print("Number of items scraped: " + str(len(products_list)))
## End of Webscrape

driver.quit()

## PRINTING RESULT FOR DEBUGGING 
count = 0
for x in products_list:
   print(x)
   print(x.url)
   print("Price is: " + str(x.price))
   print("Previous Price is: " + str(x.previous_price))
   print("Item title: " + str(x.title))
   print("Number of review: "+ str(x.number_of_reviews))
   print("Review Scores: " + str(x.review_score))


   print("__________")
```

And this is the result I get:

```
Number of items scraped: 83
<reference_functions.Product object at 0x7ffd78e8bf10>
https://www.amazon.com/
Price is: []
Previous Price is: []
Item title: []
Number of review: []
Review Scores: ['4.6 out of 5 stars.', '4.6 out of 5 stars.', '4.6 out of 5 stars.']
__________
<reference_functions.Product object at 0x7ffd78eb10d0>
/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_atf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A05122932N0ETGH50WEB2&url=%2FWatches-Chronograph-Stainless-Waterproof-Business%2Fdp%2FB07Z62B354%2Fref%3Dsr_1_1_sspa%3Fcrid%3DIFKI3E407I9T%26keywords%3Dinvicta%2Bmens%2Bwatch%26qid%3D1640751697%26sprefix%3Di%252Caps%252C70%26sr%3D8-1-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1640751697&id=2139685257788988&widgetName=sp_atf
Price is: ['42']
Previous Price is: ['$49.99']
Item title: []
Number of review: ['6,012']
Review Scores: ['4.4 out of 5 stars']
__________
<reference_functions.Product object at 0x7ffd78eb12e0>
/Invicta-Diver-Blue-Watch-26972/dp/B07GMSXZBM/ref=sr_1_2?crid=IFKI3E407I9T&keywords=invicta+mens+watch&qid=1640751697&sprefix=i%2Caps%2C70&sr=8-2
Price is: ['49']
Previous Price is: []
Item title: []
Number of review: ['6,122']
Review Scores: ['4.6 out of 5 stars']
__________
<reference_functions.Product object at 0x7ffd78eb1130>
/Invicta-Diver-Quartz-Green-30623/dp/B08447S81T/ref=sr_1_omk_3?crid=IFKI3E407I9T&keywords=invicta+mens+watch&qid=1640751697&sprefix=i%2Caps%2C70&sr=8-3
Price is: ['59']
Previous Price is: ['$69.90']
Item title: []
Number of review: ['6']
Review Scores: ['4.8 out of 5 stars']
__________
<reference_functions.Product object at 0x7ffd78eb1070>
/Invicta-12847-Specialty-Stainless-Steel/dp/B00962GV2E/ref=sr_1_4?crid=IFKI3E407I9T&keywords=invicta+mens+watch&qid=1640751697&sprefix=i%2Caps%2C70&sr=8-4
Price is: ['37']
Previous Price is: []
Item title: []
Number of review: ['5,376']
Review Scores: ['4.7 out of 5 stars']
```

Etc. Etc. Etc.

On this trial run it exported the url and the total reviews.  I find that every other run doesn't export these variables.  Is that because Amazons html changes each time I run it or is it something wrong with the code?

Any help on this would be gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use css selector to find the link since I don't find xpath reliable. The code that I would use to find the link would be:

```
product_tree.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.a-link-normal.s-no-outline').get_attribute('href')
```

Running this path for me would return the correct link every time, without any problems.
As for the reviews, I would also use css. In this case it would be:

```
product_tree.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.a-icon-alt').text
```

If it still doesn't work, I would suggest writing the whole page source to a text file by using `driver.page_source` and then use a tool to view what the driver is seeing.